# Path finding data structure for A* in python

Tags: python, data-structures, path-finding, a-star

I am using A* for pathfinding, and am creating a very limited graph to make traversal and pathfinding quick and easy.

How do I represent this as a data structure easily traversable from P0 to P1 by A* in python?

[image]

Everything is relative to points P0 and P1 which can be mirrored or 90 degree rotation to each other.

The points are at real coordinates and the other nodes are equal spaced and relative to our two points. The nodes have to remember their true coordinates so that once a path is chosen it can easily be drawn.

The weights on the edges are preweighted to give the resulting path an aesthetic look I prefer. The weights don't change so these can be pregenerated.  However, there may be objects within the space that dynamically affect the weight of some edges (thus the need for pathfinding).

Pathfinding will happen every frame, so every 1/25th sec. So points for efficiency.

Here's the algorithm I'm trying to put together:

1. Find the short and long side of the rectangle between the cells, work out the alignment.
2. Calculate the coordinates of each node and edge.
3. Apply pre-weight to the edges.
4. Add additional weight for any nodes or edges that are blocked.
5. Use A* algorithm to find the least-cost path which favors routes
   that minimize the distance.

And to remind you, a typical A* implementation has three user-serviceable parts I need to provide:

```
def move_cost(self, c1, c2, pred=None, start=None, goal=None):
    """ Compute the cost of movement from one coordinate to another."""

def estimate(self, c1, c2):
    """ Compute the cost of movement from one coordinate to
        another. Often euclidian distance."""

def successors(self, c):
    """ Compute the successors of coordinate 'c': all the
        coordinates that can be reached by one step from 'c'."""
```

How do I generate and traverse this data structure?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your graph represents. Are you intending to find paths between arbitrary points on the graph, or just between P0 and P1? Are P0 and P1 fixed permanently, or can they move from frame to frame? Are you sure you want 0-cost path segments? That makes it very hard to come up with an [admissible heuristic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic), as that requires never overestimating the distance between two points.

Comment: This is not really a fit question for stackoverflow, as it is overly opinionate. Maybe you can write something, and then post it to codereview.se instead. As for the datastructure for storing the map, the most space efficient would be 2 two-dimensional arrays, one for edges down and one for edges to the right, say.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because there is no code, it is too broad, and after fixing those could be better answered at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Blckknght, as I wrote, I'm looking for a data structure that allows A* to find a path from P0 to P1.

Comment: Um, if the map if fixed and you're always going from P0 to P1, you don't need any data structure or A* search. Just do "Down", "Down", "Right", "Right", "Down", "Down" unconditionally. Cost is 0.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, this is very much suited to stackoverflow.  I am asking for suggestions for representing a data structure in python. I provide the other info as context to help responders understand how I am using the data structure. This is the heart of the question, "How do I represent this as a data structure easily traversable from P0 to P1 by A* in python?"

Comment: @Blckknght: There may be "blocks" dynamically effecting the weights. "4. Add additional weight for any nodes or edges that are blocked." And I clarified this point above.

Comment: @Blckknght, However you did discover the preferred path. :-)

Comment: Um, you need to explain that a lot more then. How are the "blocks" determined? Do they change over time? What does it mean for P0 and P1 to be "mirrored or rotated" relative to each other? As it is, this question is not going to get a useful answer, as you haven't really explained what you're trying to achieve. Just saying "I need a data structure" doesn't help if the problem is nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

This is a large and complicated question and would benefit from being broken into smaller questions. Here are some thoughts to help you differentiate some sub problems that you've posed:

- The traversal of the graph structure does not depend on geometry, only on the cost assigned to each edge. This cost can include distance if you'd like.
- Since the path finding algorithm is geometry-agnostic (but may include distance in its cost function) the geometric layout of your nodes is a separate problem. You can think of the node coordinates as arbitrary attributes assigned to each node that may be used to calculate the cost (if you want cost to be distance-dependent).
- The data structure for traversals would be a graph object with node and edge classes, and would allow you to assign and edit the weights assigned to each edge, or to add and remove edges whenever you want to create 'blocks'.
- If you intended to vary the source and destination nodes used to calculate the paths, you should use a bidirectional graph.
- You said "there may be objects within the space that dynamically affect the weight of some edges". The location of these objects and the functions do determine when and how much they affect the weights would be yet another separate task.

Here's the main things you need:

1. The **undirected graph structure** (includes nodes, edges, attributes and the ability to access a cost function in order to solve for the least cost path)
2. The **cost function**. This should take an edge as an argument, and if necessary, should read attributes from the nodes associated with that edge to calculate the cost.
3. The interfering objects, I will call them '**attractors**'.
4. An **'effect' function** that determines how the attractors edit the graph structure or edge weights. This might include a distance search that determines the nodes or edges that fall within a particular range of the attractor.
5. **Generating the initial coordinates and weights**.

The **undirected graph structure** is very easy to implement using [NetworkX](http://networkx.github.io/). NetworkX allows you to attach arbitrary attributes to nodes and edges, is well-documented with many examples, and includes [multiple least-cost pathfinding algorithms](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms.shortest_paths.html). NetworkX also allows you to designate a custom cost function for determining edge traversal costs.